# Where would something that needs to be called first on every page load would go in blazor?

Tags: blazor

I read the blazor lifecycle doc but I am still not sure where I can put something that I absolutely have to have executed as the first thing on the page load.

For example:

I am implementing a simple login. I use localstorage to save the authenticated user with one of the object fields being the time inserted into local storage so I can compare it to DateTime.Now to see if the object expired should the user hit f5.

The comparison needs to happen as the very first thing on the page load. So I put it into the `OnInitialized` of the layout page all my pages use. Issue is `OnInitialized` of the child page gets called before `OnInitialized` of the layout page and the child expects the user object to already be set to do it's thing.

**LoggedIn (main layout)**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase;

<!--- material frame --->
            @Body
<!--- /material frame --->

@code
{

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("parent");
    }
}
```

**Exams (child)**

```
@layout WebApp.Shared.Layouts.LoggedIn;

<! --- stuff ----.
@page "/app/examinations"
<! --- /stuff ----.
}

@code {


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("child");
     }

}
```

Comment: What you really want to know is why the `OnInitialized` in the main layout isn't called first? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. OR am I wrong about my assumptions and something like what I am describing should be handled differently in blazor.

Comment: Could you please show how you handle the main layout ?

Comment: @Vencovsky Updated

Answer (score 1):

`OnInitialized` should not be used to handle authentication. However, Blazor has an authentication framework built in that you can take advantage of:

1. Implement a custom `AuthenticationStateProvider`, overriding
   `GetAuthenticationStateAsync` with the logic that determines whether
   or not your user is logged in.
2. Register your new
   `AuthenticationStateProvider` in your client-side startup
3. Add on
   the `[Authorize]` attribute to any page that requires a login

Microsoft [full documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: This may be but I am not sure it solved my problem. My problem is not authentication my problem is checking the expiration before anything else happens in the app. I don't see anything about this in the documentation which leads me to believe it'll still has to be done manually (as I am doing right now) which will bring me to the same issue. Am I missing something?

Comment: You should be checking if your authorization token is expired as part of GetAuthenticationStateAsync. If the user has no auth token, or has an expired auth token, return an anonymous claim.